# Setting Background-Image in React

Tags: reactjs, css, jsx

I want the image to behave as if it was set as an background-url and function like this:

```
img.thisIsMyImage {
 background: url("../../services/images/hehe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover; 

animation: increase 60s linear 10ms infinite;
-webkit-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
-moz-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
-ms-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
-o-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
```

}

This is the React Code

```
 render() {
    return (
    <div>
        <img src={rsm_logo} className="thisIsMyImage" alt="containerLogo" />
        <LoginForm submit={this.submit} />
    </div>
    )
}
```

This works perfectly fine when done like the code above in the CSS, but i want it to be applied to the element that is in the .jsx code on the element "*thisIsMyImage*" and stil have the same behaviour as in the css code.

Any suggestions are much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*BackgroundImage.js*

```
import './YourFileName.css'
import Image from '../path/path/path/image.jpeg'

export const BackgroundImage = () => {
    return (
      <>
        <img className="backgroundImage" src={Image} alt={"Error"} />
      </>
    )
}
```

*YourFileName.css*

```
.backgroundImage {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need import css file into react component like this:

```
 // remove "img" from class in css
 img.thisIsMyImage {
     background: url("../../services/images/hehe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  }

 // like this:
 .thisIsMyImage {
   background: url("../../services/images/hehe.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
 }
```

In react component import your css file:

```
import from './styles.css'

<img src={rsm_logo} className="thisIsMyImage" alt="containerLogo" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using src and background in img tag together? It's weird to use img tag here. Img src will take precedence. You may have to provide suitable width & height for the image to show up.

I have attached an example with div and img tag.

```css
.thisIsMyImage {
    background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/150") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover; 
    animation: increase 60s linear 10ms infinite;
    -webkit-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 5.2s ease-in-out;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="thisIsMyImage" title="containerImage"></div>

<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="thisIsMyImage" title="containerImage" />
```

Import the css in the main file to avoid multiple imports.

```
import from './styles.css'
```

And in the render function, I suggest to use a div instead of img tag if you are going to use background & background-related-properties.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="thisIsMyImage" title="containerLogo" />
      <LoginForm submit={this.submit} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can import css and set the class

```js
class Hello extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
     <div>
       Hello {this.props.name}
        
        <div className='imgStyle' />
      </div>
  );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.imgStyle {
  background: url("https://placekitten.com/600/200") no-repeat center center fixed; 
  
  width: 600px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
</div>
```